# Optimization for fetching recording from AWS dynamoDB using glueContext python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-glue

I have written the below code to fetch records from the DynamoDB and apply a filter on a column department. But the problem here is while fetching all the records it Scan the whole AWS DynamoDB table which comes with a Cost Overhead. I want to optimize this to only fetch the records with a column **department**.
Can someone help me with this, A better-optimized approach is also appreciated.

```
def fetch_data(table_name):
    df = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame_from_options(
          connection_type="dynamodb"
          connection_options = {
              "dynamodb.input.tableName" : table_name,
              "dynamodb.throughput.read.percent":"1.0"
          }
      ).toDF()
     return df.filter(df.department == "Finance") if df.count() > 0 else df
```

Comment: Looking at the docs, I am not sure such an option exists when using create_dynamic_frame_from_options(). Here are all available options: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-etl-connect.html#aws-glue-programming-etl-connect-dynamodb

Comment: Maybe a solution like this can work for you in some way? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/prescriptive-guidance/latest/dynamodb-full-table-copy-options/aws-glue.html

From the docs: The solution is efficient for large datasets because the export feature uses the DynamoDB backup functionality, so it does not do a scan on the source table, It does not consume any provisioned capacity on the source table, There's no impact on the performance or availability of the source table.

Comment: Use as per your usecase a good comparision. https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/accelerate-amazon-dynamodb-data-access-in-aws-glue-jobs-using-the-new-aws-glue-dynamodb-elt-connector/